# Видимость приватных полей вложенного класса во внешнем классе - Java

Tags: java

Собственно вопрос - почему поля private вложенного статического класса видны во внешнем классе?

Comment: В [jls-6.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1) сказано: "Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared private, and access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level type (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor."

Answer (score 1):

Статический вложенный класс или интерфейс определен как static член окружающего класса, что делает его аналогом поля и метода класса, которые так же объявлены как static. Вложенный класс имеет доступ к членам своего внешнего класса, в том числе и к закрытым членам. Однако, внешний класс не имеет доступа к членам вложенного класса.

Вот еще хорошая [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/342090/)